# comparing strings within a jQuery .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a list item, based on the text content of the item - it's a workaround to highlight items in a dynamically generated menu, but the class gets applied to all the list items. Is it going wrong because I'm comparing two different kinds of variable?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('article[id^=post]').filter(function(){
            var categorySelected = this.className.match(/\bcategory-\w+\b/).toString();
            var trimmed = categorySelected.replace(/^category-/,''); 
            if ( $(this).hasClass(trimmed) ) {
                alert ('article has category = true, location = ' + trimmed );
                    $('div#categories-3 li').each(function(index) {
                        var listItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-').toString();
                        if ( listItem = trimmed ) {
                            alert ('listItem = ' + listItem + ' trimmed = ' + trimmed); 
                            $(this).addClass('current-cat'); 
                        };
                    });
            };
        });
    });
```

..thanks for the suggestions, have made the change and put more diagnostics in, but still can't make the breakthrough. In this version the 'current-cat' class never gets added:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('article[id^=post]').filter(function(){
            var categorySelected = this.className.match(/\bcategory-\w+\b/).toString();
            var trimmed = categorySelected.replace(/^category-/,''); 
                if ( $(this).hasClass(trimmed) ) {
                    alert ('article has category = true\nlocation = ' + trimmed + '\ntrimmed var is type of ' + (typeof trimmed) );
                        $('.cat-item').each(function(index) {
                            $(this).addClass('item-' + index);
                            var listItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
                            alert ( 'listItem var is type of ' + typeof listItem ) ;
                            if ( listItem == trimmed ) {
                                 alert ('listItem = ' + listItem + ' trimmed = ' + trimmed); 
                                 $(this).addClass('current-cat'); 
                                 }

                        });
                    };
        });
    });
```

here is the HTML it's for:

```
    <div id="container">
        <article id="post-49" class="post-49 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-reykjavik reykjavik photograph">
            some content 
        </article>
        <div id="categories-3" class="widget widget_categories">
            <h4 class="widgettitle">
                Location 
            </h4>
            <ul>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
                    <a href="#">
                        Havana 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-3">
                    <a href="#">
                        London 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
                    <a href="#">
                        Reykjavík 
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the basic structure of the html so we can test against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the comparison is never true because of whitespace and line feeds.

```
if (listItem == trimmed) {
```

debug it by adding a console line [better than alert] in front of the if

```
console.log(listItem + "\t" + trimmed);
if (listItem == trimmed) {
```

Also for a performance boost, you should not keep calling `$(this)` over and over again. It make a new jQuery object each time which makes the code run longer. Cache it into a variable and use that variable over and over again.

Comment: brilliant & thanks for student answer - looks like there's some UTF-8 to deal with too - will post code when it's completely fixed

Answer (score 2):

Change  `if ( listItem = trimmed )` To  `if ( listItem == trimmed )`

Comment: while I see all answers the same, don't know why new answers copy paste it in a new answer, also I can't understand why this question is taking these up ratings, hmmmm..

Comment: is it possible to see why ( listItem == trimmed ) will always be false in my code?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( listItem = trimmed ) {
```

should be

```
if ( listItem == trimmed ) {
```

Comment: thanks - this makes the condition always false, so the class never gets added, but in the alert box the two strings appear to be the same

Comment: correction: the strings had appeared to be the same, now the block with the alert isn't executed

Comment: Can you do console.log to write out the values for listItem and trimmed?  Or move the alert to before that IF statement

Comment: I moved the alert to before the IF. It loops through the list, and reports listItem and trimmed as expected - one pair appears to match, as that IF block is meant to detect

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( listItem = trimmed )
```

this assigns trimmed to listItem and then checks if something is assigned to listItem which is always true.

You need to do

```
if ( listItem == trimmed )
```

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of the [replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to strip whitespace and linefeeds from the text in the list items, this code now works as expected, but it highlights a problem which will occur if the text contains Unicode characters:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('article[id^=post]').filter(function(){
            var categorySelected = this.className.match(/\bcategory-\w+\b/).toString();
            var trimmed = categorySelected.replace(/^category-/,''); 
                if ( $(this).hasClass(trimmed) ) {
                        $('.cat-item').each(function(index) {
                            var myListItem = $(this);
                            var theListItem = myListItem.text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
                            theListItem = theListItem.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,'');
                            if ( theListItem == trimmed ) {
                                 myListItem.addClass('current-cat'); 
                                 }
                        });
                };
        });
    });
```